# how to access $loader variable from within a class?

Tags: php, symfony, scope

app/config/routing.php

This is how it should be done

```
$collection = new RouteCollection();

$collection->addCollection(
// second argument is the type, which is required to enable
// the annotation reader for this resource
    $loader->import("@AppBundle/Controller/", "annotation")
);

return $this->collection;
```

I need to create  a more complex routing system for a company, 
and need to be able to register routes from within a class.

```
class AutoRouter extends AppKernel
{ 
    function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function registerControllers()
    {
        $collection = new RouteCollection();
        global $loader;
        $collection->addCollection(
            // second argument is the type, which is required to enable
            // the annotation reader for this resource
            $loader->import("@AppBundle/Controller/", "annotation")
        );

        return $this->collection;
    }
    //(....)
}
```

tldr; I need to access the import function from the registerControllers method, but it throws this error

> UndefinedMethodException: Attempted to call method "import" on class
>   "Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader"

```
// Answer

    use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

    class AutoRouter extends AppKernel
    {
        private $collection;

        public function registerControllers($loader)
        {
            $collection = new RouteCollection();
            $collection->addCollection(
                // second argument is the type, which is required to enable
                // the annotation reader for this resource
                $loader->import("@AppBundle/Controller/", "annotation")
            );

            return $this->collection;
        }

        public function getActiveBundles()
        {
            return $this->registerBundles();
        }

    }

    $at = new AutoRouter('dev', true);
    return $at->registerControllers($loader);
```

Comment: You could pass the `$loader` variable as an argument. Preferably with a type-hint

Comment: goddamn it, thanks! it was so obvious,  post it as an answer

Comment: php and javascript scopes are so different :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect opportunity to utilize [dependency injection](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dependency-injection-in-php--net-28146). You should inject the `$loader` instance as a type-hinted argument to ensure the correct object instance is provided.

```
public function registerControllers(Loader $loader) { ...
```

Using dependency injection will also make it easier to change the concrete implementation in the future without changing the 'consuming' code.

Happy coding!